How to Use Preact Signals in a CRA Project
I've a Create React App project and I'm trying to use useSignal as per this docs, but the values of signals are not rendering. (Like x.value does not render).
I've run:
npm i @preact/signals-react
npm i --save-dev @ preact/signals-react-transform

And have added a babel.config.js  file in the root:
module.exports = {
plugins: [["module:@preact/signals-react-transform"]],
}

My App.js file:
import { signal, useSignal } from '@preact/signals-react'

function App() {
    const count = useSignal(0)

    return (
        <button
            onClick={() => {
                count.value++
                console.log(count.value)
                {/* the value changes in the log */}
            }}
        >
            Value: {count.value}
            {/* not working */}
        </button>
    )
}

export default App


CRA doesn't allow customizing the Babel configuration without ejecting. One may rather use react-app-rewired.

Here's the detailed steps:
Install the react-app-rewired as dev dependency along with customize-cra and the required babel plugin (@preact/signals-react-transform):
npm i react-app-rewired customize-cra @preact/signals-react-transform -D

Replace react-scripts with react-app-rewired from scripts in package.json
"start": "react-app-rewired start",
"build": "react-app-rewired build",
"test": "react-app-rewired test",

Create a config-overrides.js file:
const { addBabelPlugins, override } = require('customize-cra')
module.exports = override(...addBabelPlugins('module:@preact/signals-react-transform'))

Run your app with npm start. 
